# confusing about load data based on router params in react component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to load data from api based on router params in component,

The channel page behave as expected when I first open the page, but if I go to other channel page by clicking, `ChannelPage` component didn't call `componentDidMount`, but reducer received `FETCH_MESSAGES` action, the `Sidebar` component also have the problem. redux-devtools can only received `LOCATION_CHANGE` action when other channel page get clicked. it's too weird!

What's the best practice for loading data based on params in react component?

Sidebar

```
class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchChannels(1);
  }

  openChannelPage = (e, url) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('open channel page');
    this.props.changeRoute(url);
  };

  render() {
    let channelsContent = null;

    if (this.props.channels !== false) {
      channelsContent = this.props.channels.map((item, index) => (
        <ChannelItem
          routeParams={this.props.params} item={item} key={`item-${index}`} href={item.url}
          handleRoute={(e) => this.openChannelPage(e, item.url)}
        />
      ), this);
    }

    return (
      <div id="direct_messages">
        <h2 className={styles.channels_header}>messages</h2>
        <ul>
          {channelsContent}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  channels: selectChannels(),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  changeRoute: (url) => dispatch(push(url)),
  fetchChannels: () => dispatch(fetchChannels()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Sidebar);
```

ChannelPage

```
class ChannelPage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('##Fetch history messages##');
    this.props.fetchMessages(this.props.channel);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {this.props.channel.name}
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  channel: selectChannel(),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  fetchMessages,
})(ChannelPage);
```

appReducer

```
function appReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_CHANNELS:
      console.log('received channels');
      return state;
    case FETCH_CHANNELS:
      console.log('fetching channels');
      return state;
    case FETCH_MESSAGES:
      console.log('fetching history messages---WTF');
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default appReducer;
```

reducer received unexpected `FETCH_MESSAGES` action
[image: demo]

redux-devtools can only received `LOCATION_CHANGE` action when go to other channel page
[image: redux-devtools]

Which one is the right behavior?

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions

> What's the best practice for loading data based on params in react component?

You can use [componentDidUpdate()](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md#fetching-data) to dispatch request based on router params to get data from API

> reducer received unexpected `FETCH_MESSAGES` action when navigate from `messages/1` to `messages/2`

It's an expected behavior, reducer will receive previous action when navigate from `messages/1` to `messages/2`, and the `componentDidMount` already ran once so it will never be called